# JAVA library path INPUT/OUTPUT for DLL

Tags: java, tomcat, dll, java-native-interface

I have java web application which calls `C` classes compiled into `.DLL`. Current `DLL` requires INPUT file and uses it as a dictionary. My web application deployed on Tomcat - so in order to make everything working I have to put my dictionary input file under `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.14\bin` directory, otherwise `DLL` unable to find it.

I think this is not a great location for my input file. Could you please suggest how can I configure different location for my input file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you modify the C code?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, I can, but deployment URL is always different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your native C code to accept a file path, this becomes less of an issue, since your Java code can specify the location of the file.

In your Java class:

```
public class Test {
  public native void toSomethingWithDictionary(String dictionaryFile);
}
```

In your C code:

```
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "test.h"

#define ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH 255

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_toSomethingWithDictionary
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring dictionaryFile)
{
    FILE *dict;
    const char *dict_path;

    dict_path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, dictionaryFile, 0);

    if(NULL == (dict = fopen(dict_path, "r"))) {
      /* Failed to open the file. Why? */
      char error_msg[ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH];

      strerror_r(errno, error_msg, ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

      strncat(error_msg, ": ", ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH - strlen(error_msg) - 1);

      strncat(error_msg, dict_path, ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH - strlen(error_msg) - 1);

      jclass ioe = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/IOException");
      if(NULL == ioe) {
        goto cleanup;
      }
      (*env)->ThrowNew(env, ioe, error_msg);
      goto cleanup;
    }

    /* do whatever you want with your dictionary file */

    fclose(dict);

    cleanup:
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, dictionaryFile, dict_path);
}
```

If you'd prefer to have a more complicated interface to the `Test` class, you could have a `public void setDictionaryPath(String dictionaryPath)` method and then have your native code use that to locate the file.

Now, when you are ready to use the class from within your web application, just do this:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.doSomethingWithDictionary("/usr/share/dict/words");
```

Or, if you want to put the file onto the disk somewhere dynamic:

```
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
Test test = new Test();
test.doSomethingWithDictionary(app.getRealPath("/META-INF/dict"));
/* NOTE: getRealPath is a bad API call to use. Find a better way. */
```